# Pooling data from multiple csv files into a cell

Tags: matlab, csv, cell

I have 33 csv files from different locations and I would like retrieve each file, get the content and dump it in a cell. This cell should contain information (all scalar values) from all the individual files. Each individual file has 3 rows and 16 columns. I would like to create a 99 x 16 cell (called P). 99 rows would be from 3 rows per each of the 33 files. The 16 columns are 16 columns from each file.

So far I have created a loop to retrieve each file:

P=cell(length(Q)*3,16); % Q contain the name of the files

for k=1:length(Q)

dire_FIX = '/Data3/ledata/FHSWD/Scan_data/';

data_path=[dire_FIX Q{k}];

data = spm_select('FPList', fullfile(data_path), sprintf('^%s.*\.csv$', Q{k})); % get each file

Values = load (data)

Here is where I got stuck. Values should be a 3x16 cell. How do I put each Values into P without overwriting the previous Values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize P to an empty matrix:

```
P =[];
```

Put this at the end of your for-loop:

```
P(:, end+1) = Values{:, 1};
P(:, end+1) = Values{:, 2};
P(:, end+1) = Values{:, 3};
```

That should do it.

Comment: I ended using P(end+1,1:16). Thank you, Fletch.